# Does the lowest eigenvector have a nonvanishing component along a basis with the lowest diagonal value of a Hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a $N\times N$ Hermitian matrix $\hat H$ written in a basis $\{\hat e_1,\hat e_2,.., \hat e_N\}$ with $H_{11}$ being the lowest diagonal element.

Let  $V_1=c_1 \hat e_1+ c_2 \hat e_2 +...+c_N \hat e_N$ be the eigenvector with the lowest eigenvalue.

Is $c_1>0$ for at least large N?

In other words, is there a theorem that requires the lowest eigenvector must have a nonvanishing component for the basis that gives lowest diagonal element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $H=\pmatrix{0\\ &1&2\\ &2&1}$. Its spectrum is $\{0,-1,3\}$ and the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$ is the span of $(0,1,-1)^\top$. You may attach more copies of the subblock $\pmatrix{1&2\\ 2&1}$ diagonally to $H$ to extend the counterexample to higher dimensions.